# switch database by ip or something else

Tags: python, django

this is my setting about database in django settings.py
the method I use now is use a parameter `TEST`,if TEST ==True ,use the db in my computer.
else : use RDS on AWS 
I want to know how to decide which database to use base on ip or something

Please guide me Thank you!

```
TEST = True
if TEST==True:
    DATABASES = {   # localhost
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
            "NAME": " ",
            "USER": " ",
            # "PASSWORD": " ",
            "HOST": "localhost",
            "PORT": "5432",
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {  #aws
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': " ",
            'USER': " ",
            'PASSWORD': " ",
            'HOST': "xxx.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com" ,
            'PORT': "5432",
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that you're looking for a way to determine the IP of the system executing your code?

Comment: I mean I want to use ip to switch database.Because I have to change the TEST=TRUE,TEST=FALSE by my self.Sometimes I forget to change,then my data is save to RDS, not the test environment on my localhost.

Comment: This sounds like a job for environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another viable option I forgot to mention is using environment variables. You could set the environment variables, in your wsgi file like so:

```
os.environ['VARNAME'] = 'value'
```

and if you're using a virtual environ put this in you activate script:

```
export VARNAME='value'
```

and then in your settings.py file you would have something like:

```
env = os.environ['ENV']

if env == "dev":
    DATABASES = {   # localhost
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
            "NAME": " ",
            "USER": " ",
            # "PASSWORD": " ",
            "HOST": "localhost",
            "PORT": "5432",
        }
    }
elif env == "prod":
    DATABASES = {  #aws
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': " ",
            'USER': " ",
            'PASSWORD': " ",
            'HOST': "xxx.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com" ,
            'PORT': "5432",
        }
    }
```

There are a few ways to set the environment variables depending on your setup, but I usually either add into the activate file of my virtualenv, or add it into the wsgi file

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a question ,nomatter settings file for ````prod and dev````  or setting ````export ENV='dev'```` I still have to change now is dev or prod ?? right???

Comment: no, your environment variables you set will be different. in the dev environment you run export ENV='dev' and in your prod enviornment you would run export ENV='prod' and you wouldn't have to change anything in your code

Comment: Oh!it's really cool! Thank you very much. so where should I put this ````export ENV='dev'```` ??

Comment: In your wsgi file put something like os.enviorn['varname']="value". And then if you're using a virtual env you'll want to put export varname='value' in your activate script

Comment: I found that after I write base.py prod.py dev.py. It can't find the static files and templates.Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You should use different settings file for prod and dev. You can have a base settings file that has shared settings, and then import the base settings file and change the variables that are different for dev/prod (in this case, DATABASES)

This way you won't have to remember to change anything, and your settings will be cleaner and source controllable. Make sure in the wsgi.py you're loading the correct settings file.

settings/base.py

```
# shared things go in here
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
)

...
```

settings/dev.py

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

DATABASES = {   # localhost
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": " ",
        "USER": " ",
        # "PASSWORD": " ",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}
```

settings/prod.py

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

DATABASES = {  #aws
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': " ",
        'USER': " ",
        'PASSWORD': " ",
        'HOST': "xxx.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com" ,
        'PORT': "5432",
    }
}
```